# Symfony 3.2.2 - UrlRedirect works without configuration

Tags: php, caching, symfony, redirect

I have a YAML configuration file that used to redirect specific routes via UrlRedirect, but now the redirects are no longer needed since the respective routes have been populated. Within the dev environment however, even after deleting cache and thoroughly looking through the whole project, the redirect keeps being executed. Where exactly can I find the source of the problem?

Comment: Seems like a kind of browser cache. Try to remove all browsers cookie, historic and so on. Try in private mode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could be a firewall configuration? If so, when you require a protected resource Symfony's firewall redirect your browser. But I do not know what is your real problem: what kind of redirection you have? From where? To login page or other page?

Comment: There were several "subpages" for general topics in my site hierarchy - they used to be required for the breadcrumb template only, and would redirect to "subsubpages". Now, the "subpages" are populated with content as well, but the redirections were still working.

Comment: But, as for now, after deleting browser-cache, symfony cache, and countless reloadings, the dev environment seems to work as well. So my question is obsolete and can be closed. But nonetheless thank you for your questions :)